# Maxvalue function modification

Tags: python

I am trying to modify my function

```
def maxvalue(values):
    """
    Function that receives a list/array and returns the index of the maximum
    value in that sequence
    """    
    try:
        max_value = max(values)
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("Only numerical values are allowed")  # raise an exception if the value is not float or integer

    indices = []
    for idx, val in enumerate(values):
        if val == max_value:
            indices.append(idx)
    return indices
```

Such that it will still return the index of the maximum value in the sequence as well as the TypeError.
I have another function, sumvalues which does this

```
def sumvalues(values):
    """
    Function that receives a list/arrary and returns the sum of the values in that 
    sequence
    """  
    total = 0.0
    for value in values:
        try:
            total += value
        except TypeError: #Values are still sumed up, if non-numercial are detected, prints the message
            print("Only numerical values are allowed") 
    return total
```

calling the `maxvalue` function:

```
print(maxvalue([1,2,3,3,"e"]))
```

should output:

```
Only numerical values are allowed

[2,3]
```

Comment: You can't return a list of ints *and* raise a `TypeError`.  It's got to be one or the other.  If you want to return multiple values, you might want to return a tuple (e.g. a list of ints and an error string), but that's "unpythonic" -- a function *should* generally either succeed or fail, not return a possible partial success plus a possible failure message.

Comment: I'd say `maxvalue` does it right (throws if given rubbish) and `sumvalues` is wrong, so you'll be better off fixing the latter.